# Conditional based on day of week

Tags: smarty

I would like to print out a different string of text based on the current day of the week. Any advice?

Am I on the right track with this:

```
{if $current_timestamp|date_format:"%A" == 'Monday'}
    Monday
{elseif $current_timestamp|date_format:"%A" == 'Tuesday'}
    Tuesday
{elseif $current_timestamp|date_format:"%A" == 'Wednesday'}
    Wednesday
{elseif $current_timestamp|date_format:"%A" == 'Thursday'}
    Thursday
{elseif $current_timestamp|date_format:"%A" == 'Friday'}
    Friday
{else}
    Weekend
{/if}
```

This is currently working for me but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way.

P.S. I won't be printing out the name of the day of the week, that's just my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should learn to "cache" your values:

```
{assign var="weekday" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%u"}
{if $weekday == 1} Monday
…
{elseif $weekday == 7} Sunday
{/if}
```